# Compiling parts of Java app with debugging symbols

Tags: java, compiler-construction, debug-symbols

I'm looking into using this library for our Java-application: http://code.google.com/p/aparapi/. One requirement for this library is that the code is compiled with debugging symbols. I.e. with the -g parameter enabled (see their [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/aparapi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)). We don't want to enable debugging information for our entire app. Is it possible to only compile the classes that interact with this library using -g and then compile the rest of the code without any debugging information (possibly even obfuscate the rest of the code).

Comment: Take a look at [Byteman](http://www.jboss.org/byteman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you only need to compile the 'Kernel' class using -g.

If your kernel is an anonymous inner class this can be tricky ;) but you can compiler the containing class with -g.  Then copy the ${n}.class file to one side and recompile without -g and copy the ${n}.class file with debug symbols over the one without.  If that makes sense.

I should have been clearer in the FAQ. I will make this change to the FAQ.

Gary